# Does the degree of the splitting field of any irreducible $n$-degree polynomial equal $n$?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

I am following example 50.9 of Fraleigh's first course in abstract algebra, 7 edition.

I want to find the degree of the splitting field of $f(x) = x^3 - 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I verified that $f(x)$ factors into a product of $(x-2^{1/3})(x^2 + 2^{1/3}x + 2^{2/3} )$. The author says (without doing any calculations) that $x^2 + 2^{1/3}x + 2^{2/3}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$(how can he see this without doing a calculation?), and hence the splitting field of $x^2 + 2^{1/3}x + 2^{2/3}$ has degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$. How can he see this? Is the splitting field of every irreducible quadratic polynomial degree 2? Does this extend to polynomials of degree $n$ somehow?

Comment: The degree of the splitting field of $X^3-2$ is $6$, This question has already been answered many times here. It is generated by $2^{1/3}$ and a third root of the unity.

Comment: the second degree polynomial in question has imaginary roots so no roots in the cubic field.. yes, for quadratics( irreducible)  the splitting field is of degree $2$. For a "random" irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ the splitting field is of degree $n!$. So a big difference.